# Mock get parameters symfony2 and phpunit

Tags: symfony, unit-testing, phpunit

I would like to test one controller that it has:

$deviceGet = strtolower($request->query->get('device'));

My question is: How can I mock it to test in my controller?

```
class SetDeviceListenerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {


     /**
     * @test
     * @dataProvider deviceGetCases
     */
public function shouldSetRequestDeviceWithDeviceGetOnMasterRequest(
    ?string $device
): void {
    $request = $this->getRequestMock();

    $request->expects($this->once())
        ->method('get')
        ->with('device')
        ->willReturn($device);


    /* @var Request $request */
    $request->server = new ServerBag();
    $request->headers = new HeaderBag();

    $event = $this->getEventMock();
    $event->expects($this->once())
        ->method('isMasterRequest')
        ->willReturn(true);
```

It return error because

```
 $request->expects($this->once())
        ->method('get')
        ->with('device')
        ->willReturn($device);
```

fails

thank you!!

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer myself (I just needed a friend):

`$request->query= new ParameterBag(['device'=>$device]);`